# How to export url with data points into excel with two columns

Tags: python, pandas

```
import pandas as pd

url = 'https://m-selig.ae.illinois.edu/ads/coord/2032c.dat'
df =  pd.read_table(url, header=None, skiprows=2, sep=('\t'), engine='python')
df.to_excel('data_1.xlsx', index=False, header=False)
```

The url includes the x and y coordinates. When I make the url into an excel file the points are in a single column. How can I make it into two columns?

Answer (score 1):

This should allow you to split the X and Y into 2 separate columns (I wasn't sure which was X and which was Y so you might need to change the column names a little)

```
url = 'https://m-selig.ae.illinois.edu/ads/coord/2032c.dat'
df =  pd.read_table(url, header=None, skiprows=2, sep=('\t'), engine='python')
df[0] = df[0].str.strip(' ')
df[['X', 'Y']] = df[0].str.split('  ', 1, expand = True)
df[['X', 'Y']]
```

Comment: When I run that code It gives me three columns, the first column includes all the points. Second and Third where it splits correctly into X and Y coordinates. How can I get rid of the first column?

Comment: in the `df[['X', 'Y']]` you can replace that line with `df = df[['X', 'Y']]`